# How to handle Scroll bars while developing test scripts in Sikuli for automation

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

I am automating a page which is designed in Flex, so i am writing scripts in Sikuli. Now i want to move the scroll bar up and down. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

With Sikuli it's pretty easy to scroll I've done it already.

Use the **wheel function**

```
wheel(WHEEL_DOWN, 4)  # Scrolls down 4 times 
wheel(WHEEL_UP,   12) # Scrolls up   12 times
```

Comment: just an addition that we need to import `import org.sikuli.script.Button;` `button = new Button();` `screen.wheel(RegionForScroll, button.WHEEL_UP, 5);`

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there is not a function to move the scrollbar. 
But you can use `dragDrop()` to move it.

For example:

```
ImageScrollbar = ("bar.png") # Make for example a image of those 3 stripes on the scrollbar.
# Locate the scrollbar 
regionScrollbar = find(ImageScrollbar)
# Move the scrollbar vertically down 
dragDrop(regionScrollbar, Location(regionScrollbar.getX(), regionScrollbar.getY() + 100))
```